# Using bootstrap with Zepto Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zepto

in html with jade

```
link(rel="stylesheet",href="/stylesheets/index/index.css")
script(src="/javascripts/assets/jquery_loader.js")
script(src="/javascripts/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.js")
```

im using modernizr to load zepto or jquery if IE is the browser

```
Modernizr.load(
{
    test: /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    yep: '/javascripts/assets/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
    nope: '/javascripts/assets/zepto/zepto.min.js',
    complete:function()
    {
        if(!window.jQuery)
        {
            Zepto.browser = {webkit: true}
            window.jQuery = Zepto
        }
    }
});
```

i receive this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:60
```

on line :60

```
}(window.jQuery);
```

i try to load bootstrap with modernizr

```
Modernizr.load(
{
    test: /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    yep: ['/javascripts/assets/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js','/javascripts/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.js'],
    nope: ['/javascripts/assets/zepto/zepto.min.js','/javascripts/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.js'],
    complete:function()
    {
        if(!window.jQuery)
        {
            Zepto.browser = {webkit: true}
            window.jQuery = Zepto
        }
    }
});
```

and the error disapear but bootstrap doesnt work
so i test in console

```
typeof $().modal == 'function'
```

and the result is 'false', this means that bootstrap doesnt download from server

how can i solve this?? tnx

Comment: I don't see you loading Bootstrap **anywhere**

Comment: sry my bad, i correct the error

Comment: Are you sure the Bootstrap library being used has the Modal feature included? Also, as a suggestion, if you want to include a library for both `yep` **and** `nope`, you can use `both`.

Comment: yes bootstrap has the modal feature, and yes i use both too, i still getting the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solve the problem using this script, tnx all!

```
Modernizr.load(
{
    test: /MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    yep: '/javascripts/assets/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js',
    nope: '/javascripts/assets/zepto/zepto.min.js',
    complete:function()
    {
        if(!window.jQuery)
        {
            Zepto.browser = {webkit: true}
            window.jQuery = Zepto
            console.log('Zepto')
        }
        Modernizr.load(
        {
            load:'/javascripts/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.js',
            complete:function()
            {
                console.log('Loaded!')
            },
        })
    },
});
```